# Find duplicates within a given date range

Tags: sql, duplicates, date-range

I'm trying to find a query which will return all entries in the database set that has duplicate signum(identifiers) and who are inside a given date range.

I tried something like this:

```
select * from dmt_teamresource where dmt_teamresource.signum IN (
select dmt_teamresource.signum from dmt_teamresource group by dmt_teamresource.signum having count((dmt_teamresource.signum)) > 1)
```

which returns all entries from dmt_teamresource that are duplicates. Now I need to add the date range somehow. Was thinking of something like:

```
where dmt_teamresource.startdate is between '2021-01-31' and '2021-12-31'
```

But don't know how to combine the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select tr.*
from (select ts.*, count(*) over (partition by tr.signum) as cnt
      from dmt_teamresource tr
      where . . .   -- whatever conditions you want here
     ) tr
where cnt >= 2;
```

Comment: When I try to use this I get a error from HeidiSQL ,where I do the queries in, that say syntax error to use near partition by tr.signum as cnt

Comment: This is Standard SQL and window functions are common in pretty much all databases these days.  Perhaps your unnamed database is an old version of something.